# vim - restore lost file from vim undo file

Tags: vim

I accidentally deleted my .vimrc which took me weeks to config. I still keep the undofile and I think that's the only way I can restore it. Unfortunately, vim now does not allow me to undo (I guess because my current vimrc version cannot be "patched" with the last undo step).

Also, vim undo file is encoded so I cant see its content in human readable form. There was a step where I just deleted all my vimrc with `ggvGc` and so if there is a way to decode that vimundo file, I think I can restore it.

Is there anyway I can get my vimrc back? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a backup? If not it will be very hard to impossible to get it from the undo file.

Comment: @FDinoff no I don't. Why is it hard to get it from the undo file? It should be readable by vim right? and I have not setup any encryption on my local machine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18634061/1890567

Comment: Try Christian Brabandt patch in his answer to the question I linked above. The problem is vim ignores the undo file if the contents are not the same as it was the last time the undo was written. I don't know how the undo file is stored on disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as FDinoff suggested, the patch [here](https://15096456746048897543.googlegroups.com/attach/323c0e55e2106216/force_rundo.diff?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrENbcoOUOk1SUOG5yAL442otPDBIXVDiXLPoWpUIo0x955if8-yRoCNH0P_8_UkmxFvtkt5RD7h8wBOVh8Z_AEWpxhWFAFttI_MFlLYiQH7cc-TkKc) really works for me.

Comment: Great. Now go make a backup.

Comment: That patch does not apply to recent versions of `vim`. I retrieved the source from https://github.com/vim/vim/archive/v8.0.1272.tar.gz and created a patch that applies cleanly. Here it is: https://gist.github.com/Rob--W/2cf28e472aeb6b6de6e478a96e278fc8 Note that vimundo will usually not contain enough data to recover the full file, unless you did an operation that modified all lines (and even then, you would get the file before the operation, not the final version).

Comment: There are newer versions of the patch for 8.2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630937/recover-a-vim-file-from-the-un-file-without-the-undo-command/18634061#comment107393474_18673115

Answer (score 8):

For people coming here years later, it's not possible in recent versions of Vim.

You could try running this to extract what you can from the undo file:

```
$ strings <undo-file>
```

See [Recover a vim file from the .un~ file without the undo command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630937) for more information.